# grpc: Cannot restore connection for approximately 15 seconds after server restart

Tags: c#, .net, windows, grpc

The client cannot restore a connection to the server immediately after server restart. Instead, it restores connection only after 15 seconds idling. I also cannot call server with a newly created channel/client from the same process. But it successfully connected if I launch a new client instance in the separate process.

I am not sure but suppose the issue appeared after moving from 1.0.0 to 1.6.1 grpc version. Maybe any new setting was introduced to change this behavior?

My call state:

```
0. Grpc.Core.Internal.CompletionQueueSafeHandle.Pluck (Source Unavailable)
1. Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall (Source Unavailable)
2. Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall (Source Unavailable)
3. Grpc.Core.Internal.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall (Source Unavailable)
```

Comment: Have you tried to revert back to 1.0.0 to understand whether it is related?

Comment: Or tried using 1.7.1?

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe any new setting was introduced to change this behavior?

I looked in grpc release notes from 1.0.0 to 1.6.1 and found following relevevant change in [1.6 note](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases/tag/v1.6.0) (C# section):

> User handlers don't run on Grpc's thread pool anymore for extra safety.

You may have to make some code adjustment into handler.
Hope this would help.